# How to merge three different JSON files into one JSON?

Tags: php, json

I have to merge three JSON files into one JSON file but the files adding in a sequential manner without arranging by root key. (PHP or any other languages)

For example:

My Code:

index.php

```
<?php 

$a = file_get_contents('1.json');
$b = file_get_contents('2.json');
$merged = array();
$merged[] = json_decode($a, true);
$merged[] = json_decode($b,true);
$merged_json = json_encode($merged);
echo $merged_json;
?>
```

a.json

```
{
    "strikers":[
        {"name":"Narendran", "club": "Manchester United"}
    ]
}
```

b.json

```
{
    "strikers":[
        {"name":"Kannan", "club": "Arsenal"}
    ]
}
```

I need this!

```
{
    "strikers":[
        {"name":"Narendran", "club": "Manchester United"},
        {"name":"Kannan", "club": "Arsenal"}
    ]
}
```

But I got this!

```
[
  {
    "strikers":[
       {"name":"Narendran","club":"Manchester United"}
    ]
  },
  {
    "strikers":[
       {"name":"Narendran","club":"Manchester United"}
    ]
  }
]
```

Help me to find any suggestions in PHP or any other languages....!!

Comment: Please show example input And desired output. Also show us the code you have tried So far.

Comment: Added What I have tried and  I also mentioned what I need and what I'm getting.

Comment: Please add also what are the contents of the json files to begin with.

Comment: @slepic Is it fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are merging the outermost arrays. You only want to merge the `strikers` arrays:

```
$aDecoded = \json_decode('{
    "strikers":[
        {"name":"Narendran", "club": "Manchester United"}
    ]
}', true);
$bDecoded = \json_decode('{
    "strikers":[
        {"name":"Kannan", "club": "Arsenal"}
    ]
}', true);
$merged = [
  'strikers' => \array_merge($aDecoded['strikers'], $bDecoded['strikers']),
];
$merged_json = json_encode($merged, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
echo $merged_json;
```

You may want to ensure that both $aDecoded and $bDecode contains the 'striker' key and that its value is array.

Also if a and b may contain duplicities, you may need to use a loop to compare them and exclude any duplicates.

Comment: Thank You So Much...!!!!! It worked...I'm looking for this solution for the past 2 days...Thanks a Lot Once again